# Getting (405) Method Not Allowed error when trying to log in

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

I'm trying to log in to the website via C#

```
string url = "https://drs.zalohovysystem.sk/"
string param = "username=myusername&password=mypass";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = param.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                byte[] paramAsBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(param);
                stream.Write(paramAsBytes, 0, paramAsBytes.Count());
            }

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) //here i get error 405
            {
                foreach (var cookie in response.Cookies)
                {
                    var properties = cookie.GetType()
                                           .GetProperties()
                                           .Select(p => new
                                           {
                                               Name = p.Name,
                                               Value = p.GetValue(cookie)
                                           });

                    foreach (var property in properties)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I get this:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll An unhandled
> exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll The
> remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That error seems to indicate that a POST is not an accepted method at that endpoint. I would review the documentation for the website you are trying to log in to and determine if that is the correct endpoint and method for issuing your request.

Comment: Is that definitely the endpoint the website wants you to use?

Comment: You should send a `POST` request to `https://drs-function-prod.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/Auth/Login` endpoint, set the `Content-Type: application/json` and send a payload like `{"login":"x@y.com","password":"xyz"}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling the `POST` method is not allowed on the endpoint. In such cases, the most common problems are:

- You may be using a wrong endpoint (which is the case here).
- You may be using the wrong HTTP method.

**How to figure out the problem**

1. Open a browser like Chrome or Edge and browse to the login page
2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open developer tools
3. Select network tab, and make sure it's capturing the traffic (the record button should be red)
4. enter credentials and press login button.
5. See the request details, including request headers and payload tabs.

[image]

**How to send the request and get response**

You should send a:

- `POST` request to `https://drs-function-prod.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/Auth/Login` endpoint
- Set the `Content-Type: application/json`
- Send a payload like `{"login":"x@y.com","password":"xyz"}`

Then you will receive the following response:

[image]

For example:

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { login="x@y.com", password ="xyz" });
    var content = new StringContent(jsonStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(
        "https://drs-function-prod.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/Auth/Login", content);
    MessageBox.Show($"Status: {response.StatusCode}\n" +
        $"{await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()}");
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it helped :)